# Questions about subplot with GridSpec

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

plt.figure()
gspec = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 3)

top_histogram = plt.subplot(gspec[0, 1:])
side_histogram = plt.subplot(gspec[1:, 0])
lower_right = plt.subplot(gspec[1:, 1:])

X = np.random.random(size=10000)
Y = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=10000)

lower_right.scatter(X, Y)
top_histogram.hist(X, bins=100)
s=side_histogram.hist(Y, bins=100, orientation='horizontal')
```

My question is :
Why we need to add `s=` the last line of this code?

I tried to remove `s=` ,the subplots don't looks different but output will print an array.

Is anyone can tell me 
(1)
What the array means?
(2)
Why we don't need to assign variables to lower_right subplot and top_histogram subplot  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a Juypter/IPython coding environment. In such environment, the return of the last line of code gets printed out. E.g. if you type `5*3`, the return `15` will be printed.

The output of `ax.hist` are the histogrammed values, as well as the bins that were used. That is what you see in the notebook.

If you assign the result to a variable, this assignment has no return, `s = 5*3` will not print anything. Correspondingly, the histogrammed values are not printed.

Another option not to have the values printed is to use a semi-colon (`;`) at the end of the line, `5*3;`.

[image]